# C# Text box remaining empty

Tags: c#, textfield

I'm calling a public method from another class. It takes in a List as a parameter, and goes through the list printing out each item into a text field. The problem is the text field is remaining empty!. I've checked that the list is populated by outputing the item to the console before I put it into the text box, and the text is coming up fine there.

The list contains strings, and should output each string to the textfield followed by a semi colon.

This is the method which is being called:

```
public void fillAttachment(List<string> attachList)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < attachList.Count; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("List: " + attachList[i]);
    txtAttach.Text += attachList[i] + ";";
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume you are on the UI thread when calling FillAttachment?  Otherwise you'd be getting an exception thrown.  If you step through the code, breakpoint on the txtAttach... line, do you see it growing as it loops?

Comment: Try skipping the for loop to make sure. Simply set a test string to TextBox, does it work? If so, try to cache the string and then set it to the TextBox. Something like string tmpString = txtAttach.Text; then concatenate your items and finally update txtAttach.Text = tmpString;

Comment: Trying to just assign a string to the textbox doesn't work either. Must be a problem with the textbox then. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Adding to something to what is possibly a null?  Are you sure that's right?  As @SuperOli says trying initiating the txtAttach.Text property first.  Even with a txtAttach.text = String.Empty;

Answer (score 4):

I would solve it in this way:

```
foreach(var attach in attachList)
{
  Console.WriteLine(attach);
  txtAttach.AppendText(string.Format("{0};", attach));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting the text property on a text box and it not displaying could be one of the following:

- You are not looking at the same control as you are setting the text in

Could you have instantiated a second copy of the form object and it is this form that you are setting the txtAttach text property in?

Could the control that you are expecting to be populated be a different one?  Right click the text box that you want the text to appear in click properties and check the name.

- Something else is clearing the textbox after you set it

Right click the txtAttach.Text and click Find All References, this will show you all the places that the Text property is referenced - written and read - in your project.  This is a very useful way to locate other interaction with this control.

- Fomatting is making the text box appear empty

Is the Font too small, or in the same colour as the background.  Can you select the text in the text box?

The easiest way to test all of the above is to create a new text control on your form with a different name, change your code to populate it, check that it is indeed populated, then replace the old one.

As an aside, you could also reduce the code with a single line as follows:

```
public void fillAttachment(List<string> attachList)
{
    txtAttach.Text = String.Join(";", attachList.ToArray());
}
```

Although this obviously skips out the console write line function.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why yours doesn't work but I would have done it like this...

```
public void fillAttachment(List<string> attachList)
{
    string result = "";
    //OR (if you want to append to existing textbox data)
    //string result = txtAttach.Text;

    for (int i = 0; i < attachList.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("List: " + attachList[i]);
        result += attachList[i] + ";";
    }

    txtAttach.Text = result;
}
```

Does that work for you? If not then there is something else very wrong that is not obvious from your code

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either. Even just assigning a string straight to the textbox doesn't work. Not just that textbox, but trying to send the text to one of the other text boxes doesn't work either. Could it be to do with the fact that I'm calling this method from another class?